# .htaccess - redirect from www https to non www https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

It works ok when I have redirection from (example):
from http:// is redirect to correct https:// 
from http://www is redirect to correct https:// 
but when I have https://www. I don't have redirection and "non trusted connection".

What I should change in my htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect to https on your second rule too, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]
```

Not related, but you don't need to capture the path, only use `REQUEST_URI`.