# Create a rewrite rule that redirects subdomain and query strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule that changes the following rule to replace the subdomain dynamically.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^examplesubdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://examplesubdomain.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

this causes a redirect loop:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}::%{HTTPS} ^(?:www\.(.+?)::o(?:ff|n)|(?!www\.)(.+?)::off)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE,QSA]
```

Not sure what to from this point, any help would be appreciated. How do I put examplesubdomain into a variable to reuse?

EDIT: To clarify examplesubdomain could be anything, I need to move it into a variable I can echo into the destination url keeping query params along the way. I am experimenting with the following now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([\w\d]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://$1.example.com/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you mean **sub.example.com/foobar** to **sub.example.com/foobar** ?

Comment: @starkeen edited original question to clarify

Comment: Can you post an example of your old url and the new url you want to achive?

Comment: @starkeen dev.example.com -> dev.example.com but dev could be anything.

Comment: This could cause a redirect loop error  Because you want to redirect the subdomain to itself.

Comment: I don't know, if you try to get fancy, but this just looks like a redirect to https and at the same time strip www from www.example.com.

Comment: @OlafDietsche It is but i wanted the subdomain to be dynamic

Comment: I recently answered a similar question, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/37642550/1741542